# MSAccess 2013: UNION any 2 of 3 tables works, UNION all 3 crashes

Tags: sql, ms-access, crash, union

It's been years since I've worked with UNION queries in Access, but I don't see why this doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
 SELECT IDAudit, TableName, RowID, ChangeDate, IDAPSCase
 FROM dbo_APSCEI INNER JOIN (dbo_Audit INNER JOIN dbo_TableType ON dbo_Audit.IDTableType = dbo_TableType.IDTableType) 
 ON dbo_APSCEI.IDAPSCEI = dbo_Audit.RowID
 WHERE (((TableName)="APSCEI") AND ((IDAPSCase)=379017))

 UNION SELECT IDAudit, TableName, RowID, ChangeDate, IDAPSCase
 FROM dbo_APCSUN INNER JOIN (dbo_Audit INNER JOIN dbo_TableType ON dbo_Audit.IDTableType = dbo_TableType.IDTableType) 
 ON dbo_APCSUN.IDAPCSUN= dbo_Audit.RowID
 WHERE (((TableName)="APCSUN") AND ((IDAPSCase)=379017))

 UNION SELECT IDAudit, TableName, RowID, ChangeDate, IDAPSCase
 FROM dbo_APSCAI INNER JOIN (dbo_Audit INNER JOIN dbo_TableType ON     dbo_Audit.IDTableType = dbo_TableType.IDTableType) 
 ON dbo_APSCAI.IDAPSCAI = dbo_audit.RowID
 WHERE (((TableName)="APSCAI") AND ((IDAPSCase)=379017))
 ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC , IDAPSCase;
```

Individually, all 3 SELECT statements work. I can remove any 1 of the 3 SELECT statements, and it will work. But with all 3, trying to run it, or even saving it, crashes Access. But, it does save the edits, despite crashing. (Microsoft Access has stopped working. Windows can try to recover your information.)

2 of the 3 tables involved (dbo_Audit and dbo_TableType) are always the same; only the 3rd table changes. Output columns are always the same. Syntax is always the same.

If I add an extra ')' to any of the WHERE clauses, it catches the error without crashing. When I remove it and try to run or save it, it crashes Access, again. I take this to mean that the syntax checker can handle it, but the query optimizer can't.

Comment: What happens if you remove all the parentheses in the `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: @forpas - The same thing

Comment: I found something similar (maybe) that was solved by removing the ORDER BY. Give it try.

Comment: And another one that replaced `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Sonofagun! Removing the Order By clause worked. I don't see WHY that worked, when the only fields in it were common to all three subqueries. I guess I can wrap another query around the union query to handle the sorting, but that's lame.

Comment: If it solves your problem go with that

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the order by is only affecting the last query. 
If you need to order the result, make a query that calls this one like 
`SELECT * FROM MyUnionQuery ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC , IDAPSCase`
and all should be good!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying. But, Union queries can only have one Order By clause, and it's applied to the unioned superset of records.